# Color change with jQuery using class atributes

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 html text fields with class. Exmpl class name: class_name. And i would like change color after change to another field

```
$(".class_name").change(function(){
$(this).css('background-color', '00FF00');
});
```

what im doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the sample html and the element whose color has to be changed

Comment: `change` event fire after you leave textfield. Use `keyup`

Comment: `'00FF00'` isn't valid color, `'#00FF00'` is

Comment: *And i would like change color after change to another field*, did not get this?

Comment: Sorry for a bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as, It will change the background color of all controls those having class name `class_name`

```
$(".class_name").on('blur', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});
```

Or you can use as

```
$(".class_name").on('blur', function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color':'#00FF00'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Provide the Id of the text field instead of giving the class.

```
<input type="text" id="abc">

$("#abc").change(function(){
$(this).css('background-color', '00FF00');
});
```